# Is there a way to generate Connection Profile in Hyperledger Fabric automatically (with CLI)?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am currently working on Hyperledger Fabric, and I just bring up a local network based on the "Build Your First Network" tutorial from HL Fabric official site. 
  Before this, I build a network on IBM Blockchain Platform, and they have a sweet feature that can automatically build a Connection Profile for you. My question is whether Hyperledger Fabric itself has such a tool. Or, we have to manually config the connection profile and find the components by ourselves.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IBM Blockchain Platform generates the config itself, it is not a part of Fabric itself.

Comment: Did you find a way to generate this file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [composer-cli@0.10.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/composer-cli@0.10.0) with the command:

```
composer identity import -p hlfv1 -u Admin -c /home/egritos/fabric-network-on-swarm/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem -k /home/egritos/fabric-network-on-swarm/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/..._sk
```

Although `composer` is deprecated, it still the only choice I have found.